# Java: How to get path of a file when running JAR file

Tags: java

When I use relative path, I can run my Java program from Eclipse. But when I run it as a JAR file, the path doesn't work anymore. In my src/components/SettingsWindow.java I have:

`ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("./src/files/profile.ser"));`

I get a FileNotFoundException.

My file directory looks like this:
[file directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJjlj.png)

What I've tried:

`String filePath = this.getClass().getResource("/files/profile.ser").toString();`

`String filePath = this.getClass().getResource("/files/profile.ser").getPath();`

`String filePath = this.getClass().getResource("/files/profile.ser").getFile().toString();`

And I'd just put filePath in `new FileInputStream(filePath)` but none of these work and I still get a FileNotFoundException. When I `System.out.println(filePath)` it says: files/profile.ser

I'm trying to get the path of src/files/profile.ser while I'm in src/components/SettingsWindow.java

Answer (score 1):

You can get the URL to the class:

```java
        String path =                                                           
            String.join("/", getClass().getName().split(Pattern.quote(".")))    
            + ".class";                                                         
        URL url = getClass().getResource("/" + path);
```

which will either yield "file:/path/to/package/class.class" or "jar:/path/to/jar.jar!/package/class.class".  You either can work with the URL or use

```java
            JarFile jar =                                                       
                ((JarURLConnection) url.openConnection()).getJarFile();
```

and use `jar.getName()` to get the path to parse to get your installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current JAR file path I use:

```
public static String getJarFilePath() throws FileNotFoundException {
    String path = getClass().getResource(getClass().getSimpleName() + ".class").getFile();
    if(path.startsWith("/")) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("This is not a jar file: \n"+path);
    }
    if(path.lastIndexOf("!")!=-1) path = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("!/")+2, path.length());
    path = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(path).getFile();

    return path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('!')).replaceAll("%20", " ");
}
```

Comment: Could you edit the answer to provide some explanatory notes - for example, why the `if` tests, and the `%20` replacement, are needed?