# Save information beside JAR on runtime

Tags: java, maven, yaml

Since some time I've been busy learning Java and I spent most of that time working with Spigot (Minecraft) plugins.
I love how to plugins are able to copy a YAML file from resources to a folder, so a user is able to edit those YAML files.

Now I trying to find information on how I would accomplish the same effect but with just a regular JAR application, but I find it hard to find any information on how to do so.

Basicly what I wanna do is shipping an YAML with the JAR and once the application ran once, it needs to place it outside the JAR so it will use that file to get the content out of it.

Is this easy to achieve and which packages would be best to use for this purpose?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62333808/java-how-to-get-path-of-a-file-when-running-jar-file/62334505#62334505) help?

Comment: No that did not entirely what I was looking for, but I did find a solution that at least does what I want with XML files, am still checking out if this is the solution I prefer: [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)