# How to find specific file from the classpath in java

Tags: java, file

I have a project structure like below:

[image]

Now, I want to pass a specific keyword-based (which will help to find properties file in the project) on which I should directly look for that file in classpath and get it. Below is my code:

```
public class WithoutSubfolders {
    public static void main(String[] ar) throws Exception {
        WithoutSubfolders t = new WithoutSubfolders();
        String inputString = "Encounter";
        File path = t.getFileFromURL(inputString);
        HashMap< String, String> hMap = new HashMap< String, String>();
        File[] listOfFiles = path.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(listOfFiles[i]);
        }
    }

    private File getFileFromURL(String keyword) {

        URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(keyword+".*");
        File file = null;
        try {
            file = new File(url.toURI());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            file = new File(url.getPath());
        } finally {
            return file;
        }
    }
```

When I run this code, I get `Null Pointer Exception` for below line:

```
File[] listOfFiles = path.listFiles();
```

Also, I don't want to pass any extensions for the file. Something like `.*` should work. So, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem will be a lot more obvious if you add some temporary debug output for path and check value of `listFiles()` which can be null.

```
    System.out.println("path="+path);
    System.out.println("exists ? "+path.exists());
    System.out.println("isDirectory ? "+path.isDirectory());
    File[] listOfFiles = path.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; listOfFiles != null && i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(listOfFiles[i]);
    }
```

But the real cause of the error is probably because you've appended ".*" to the keyword and missed that `url == null` in getFileFromURL. Move `return` outside `finally` :

```
private File getFileFromURL(String keyword) {

    URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(keyword+".*");
    File file = null;
    try {
        file = new File(url.toURI());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        file = new File(url.getPath());
    } 
    return file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The NPE occurs because the provided path does not contain any files and isn‘t a directory. Your input string must be a valid URL to the „mappings“ directory. The path to use depends on your selected working dir of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to examine the URL and have specific code for each protocol.  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62333808/java-how-to-get-path-of-a-file-when-running-jar-file/62334505#62334505) shows how to interpret the URL.  Something like:

```java
try (JarFile jar = ((JarURLConnection) url.openConnection()).getJarFile()) {
    JarEntry entry =
        jar.stream()
        .filter(t -> ...)
        .findFirst().orElse(null);

    try (InputStream in = jar.getInputStream(entry)) {
        ...
    }
}
```